# Rounding a number to nearest fractional eighth or third in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I want to round any given number to an eighth or a third in Ruby, whichever is closest.

I'm hoping for output like `1/8` or `2/3`.

I've tried the following:

```
scalar_in_eighths = (scalar * 8.0).round / 8.0
scalar_in_thirds = (scalar * 3.0).round / 3.0

thirds_difference = (scalar - scalar_in_thirds).abs
eighths_difference = (scalar - scalar_in_eighths).abs

compute_in_thirds = thirds_difference < eighths_difference

if compute_in_thirds
  less_than_eighth = false
  rounded_scalar = scalar_in_thirds
else
  less_than_eighth = false
  rounded_scalar = scalar_in_eighths
end

quotient, modulus = rounded_scalar.to_s.split '.'
quotient = quotient.to_f
modulus = ".#{modulus}".to_f
```

This works well for eights, but for numbers like `1.32` it breaks down.

Doing `modulus.numerator` and `modulus.denominator` for the fractional components will yield numbers like `6004799503160661` and `18014398509481984`.

Is there a better way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way you could write it.

**Code**

```
def closest_fraction(f,*denominators)
  n, frac = denominators.map { |n| [n, round_to_fraction(f,n)] }
                        .min_by { |_,g| (f-g).abs }
  [(n*frac).round, n, frac] 
end

def round_to_fraction(f,n)
  (f*n).round/n.to_f
end
```

**Examples**

```
closest_fraction(2.33, 3, 8)
  #=> [7, 3, 2.3333333333333335]
closest_fraction(2.12, 3, 8)
  #=> [17, 8, 2.125]
closest_fraction(2.46, 2, 3, 5)
  #=> [5, 2, 2.5]
closest_fraction(2.76, 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17)
  #=> [47, 17, 2.764705882352941]
```

Comment: I'm not sure that this yields integers as the numerator and denominator for the thirds.

Comment: The first example returns 7/3. Is that not what you want?

Comment: Ah, my mistake. I misread. I think I'd only apply this to the modulus to get 1/3, 2/3, as that wasn't clear in my question.